# Create dictionary dinamically and automatically assign the attributes from evaluations of functions

Tags: python, dictionary

I'm working with a code that have this appearence:

module.py:

```
def attribute3():
    return "something3"


def attribute2():
    return "something2"


def attribute1():
    return "something1"
```

**main**.py:

```
from module import attribute1, attribute2, attribute3


def main():
    return {
        "attribute1": attribute1(),
        "attribute2": attribute2(),
        "attribute3": attribute3()
    }

print main()
```

And i would like to know if there is any better way to create the dictionary in the `main` function, without the necessaty of doing `"attribute: function()"`. I'm feeling like i'm repeating my self.

I don't have access to the module.py code, so i can't change to a Class.

I'm using Python 2.5 because this is a legacy software.

Thanks.

Comment: I only have 2.7, but in this version your code works perfectly. Is there a problem specific to 2.5?

Comment: Nop.. i'm just feeling like i'm repeting my self doing `attribute: function()`, i would like to know if there is a more concise way to do it.

Comment: `def main():
    d = {}
    for i in range(1,4):
        name = "attribute"+str(i)
        name2= name+"()"
        d[name] = eval(name2)
    return d`

This works, but I'm not sure how generalizable it is for you specific function names and how much sense does it make to do it like that... (sorry for no line breaks)

Comment: I think what you have is fine. You've essentially created an interface to the module; you can write a bunch of code that relies on `attribute1`, `attribute2`, etc. being in your dictionary, and if the function names change, you will only have to update the function calls in one place, instead of having to update the hash keys everywhere you use them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `getattr` and call the arbitrary functions returned.

```
import some_module

def create_dict(module, names):
    resp = {}
    for name in names: # Iterate over an arbitrary number of arguments
       # Get the function with the name provided and call it,  
       # setting the response as the value for the name
       resp[name] = getattr(module, name)()
    return resp

print create_dict(some_module, ['attribute1', 'attribute2', 'attribute3'])
```

I didn't test this on Python 2.5 but I don't see any reason why it wouldn't work.